# es posible realizar una tabla pivote con los modelos de Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Es posible crear tablas pivote en la base de datos con los modelos de Django?, necesito crear una tabla de ese tipo para relacionar emails y teléfonos de una base de datos en las tablas de empleados y clientes
[image: algo como este esquema]

es posible crear estas tablas?
como puedo hacerlo?

se que las podre realizar directamente en la base de datos pero la idea es que queden versionadas estas tablas también al igual que las que crea Django con un modelo, sera necesario solo con poner el modelo dentro de cualquier otra clase model.py?

gracias por su ayuda y comentarios!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible, se haria de la siguiente manera. declaras un campo en cualquiera de los 2 modelos, (empleados o telefonos). luego declaras que es el tipo de campo es uno de muchos a muchos, instanciando con el primer argumento el modelo con el cual se relaciona, y el campo db_table seria, el nombre que quieres que tenga en tu base de datos..

Aca te muestro un ejemplo con telefono.

```
class telefono(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ManyToManyField(Empleado, db_table="nombre_de_tabla_pivote")
```

para  mejor referencia https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Comment: muchas gracias!, ahora solo me falta ver como relacionar esa tabla pivote con las tablas de empleados y empleados :)